# Replace word in file with Username

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, sed

I am trying to replace a word in a text file with the current username. I am trying to do this with "sed" using $USER, but it keeps actually writing "$USER" in the text file instead of my username.

```
sed -i 's/test/$USER/g' ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not expanded when put inside single quotes. Use double quotes instead:

```
sed -i "s/test/"$USER"/g" ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

Also it is a good idea to take a backup while modifying file in place:

```
sed -i.bak "s/test/"$USER"/g" ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

The original file will be kept as `~/.gtkrc-2.0.bak`, the modified one will be `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.

Comment: Silly me! I tried it with double quotes earlier, but I didn't realize I needed quotes around the variable as well. Thank you for this answer, I hope it helps others too.